# In Azure DevOps, is there a way to hide Iteration and Area fields in custom work item types?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

In Azure Devops, using Customize option, you can add/modify fields except the Title, State, Reason, Area, Iteration Path. Is there a way I can modify a custom work item type to remove these fields as well?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can modify a custom work item type to remove these
> fields as well?

[System controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/system%20controls?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) like Area Path, Iteration Path and Reason can be hidden from work item form using Rest API. In additon to hide them, lables to these controls can also be edited. You can not hide Title and State. Here are the steps:

1. [Get the process ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

   Get [https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}](https://dev.azure.com/%7BOrganization%7D) /_apis/work/processes?api-version=6.0-preview.1
   [image]
2. [Update a System Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/system-controls/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples)

   PATCH [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/layout/systemcontrols/{controlId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/work/processes/%7BprocessId%7D/workItemTypes/%7BwitRefName%7D/layout/systemcontrols/%7BcontrolId%7D?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

Request Body:

```
{
  "visible": false
}
```

[image]

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, these are system fields.  There are headers elements that we'll have on each work item type:

1. **Fields**: Work item ID, Title, Assigned To, State, Reason, Area Path,
   Iteration Path, and tags
2. **Pages**: History page, Links page
   , and Attachments page.